# Inbound Email DNS setup

Tags: email, dns, installation, server

I have a problem with DNS setup (I guess).

For now, I setup with success:

Domain for web (on ovh -> points to heroku server).
Outbound emails (mailgun service)

The only thing that left, is how to setup Inbound email DNS to another server (in my case,
that will be linuxpl.com but in fact it is not important I guess).

What DNS records should I set, to achieve that. So emails sended to test@domain.com,
will get to the last email server.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add proper MX entry and wait:

In my case:

`domain.com. 0 MX 10 s87.linuxpl.com.`